# Getting ValueError while trying to convert str to datetime

Tags: python, strptime

The error that I seem to get is

```
ValueError: time data '2010-10-15' does not match format '%y-%m-%d'
```

I am failing to understand what is wrong here. Could someone please guide to what am I missing?

```
from datetime import datetime

year = datetime.strptime(data[1].split(" ")[0], "%y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: `%y` is for **two digit years**. Use `%Y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this parsing String : "%Y-%m-%d".
It should work. Refer the python docs